# Use sed or awk to replace line after match

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I'm trying to create a little script that basically uses `dig +short` to find the *IP* of a website, and then pipe that to **sed**/**awk**/**grep** to replace a line. This is what the current file looks like:

```
#Server
123.455.1.456
246.523.56.235
```

So, basically, I want to search for the '#Server' line in a text file, and then replace the two lines underneath it with an *IP* address acquired from **dig**.

I understand some of the syntax of **sed**, but I'm really having trouble figuring out how to replace two lines underneath a match. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Downvote : Show us some effort on your part to solve problems. Remember SO is not a free code for me site. Read [mcve]. A hint to start with is to use the n/N option with `sed`.

Comment: sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. For anything else, e.g. this problem, you should be using awk. Post concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can start to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's how in `awk`:

```
newip=12.34.56.78

awk -v newip=$newip '{
  if($1 == "#Server"){
    l = NR;
    print $0
  }
  else if(l>0 && NR == l+1){
    print newip
  }
  else if(l==0 || NR != l+2){
    print $0
  }
}' file > file.tmp

mv -f file.tmp file
```

explanation:

1. pass `$newip` to `awk`
2. if the first field of the current line is `#Server`, let `l` = current line number.
3. else if the current line is one past `#Server`, print the new ip.
4. else if the current row is not two past `#Server`, print the line.
5. overwrite original file with modified version.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the OP, it's not 100% clear exactly what needs to replaced where, but here's a a one-liner for the general case, using GNU **sed** and **bash**.  Replace the two lines after "**3**" with *standard input*:

```
echo Hoot Gibson | sed -e '/3/{r /dev/stdin' -e ';p;N;N;d;}' <(seq 7)
```

Outputs:

```
1
2
3
Hoot Gibson
6
7
```

Note: **sed**'s **r** command is opaquely documented (in Linux anyway).  For more about **r**, see:
"*5.9. The 'r' command isn't inserting the file into the text*" in this [sed FAQ](http://sed.sourceforge.net/grabbag/tutorials/sedfaq.txt).